# LDAP attributes with JNDI.LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I am using LDAP module for log in my webapps. I could check the login successfully with the below code.

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://my-company.com:389/ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=company,dc=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+ user +",dc=company,dc=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);

try {
// Create initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
// Close the context when we're done
b = true;
ctx.close();
}
```

But I m trying to get attributes from the connection like, Firstname, commonname,mail id etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your try block

```
SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

String[] attrIDs = { "CommonNames","firstname","givenName","uid","email"};
constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", "uid="+user, constraints);
if (answer.hasMore()) {

Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
CommonNames= (attrs.get("CommonNames").toString());
System.out.println(CommonNames);


}
```